# create contact form in jsp?

Tags: java, html, jsp, jakarta-mail

I'm able to send email by using the following code and by using Javamail API, through which I can send to any email-id using "FROM"as my "yahoo email id". The code:

mailFORM.html

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Mail form in html</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table border="1" width="50%"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
    <td width="100%">
    <form method="POST" action="mail.jsp">
    <table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <h1>Mail API</h1>
    <tr>
    <td width="50%"><b>To:</b></td>
    <td width="50%"><input type="text" name="to" size="30"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="50%"><b>From:</b></td>
    <td width="50%"><input type="text" name="from" size="30"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="50%"><b>Subject:</b></td>
    <td width="50%"><input type="text" name="subject" size="30"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="50%"><b>Description:</b></td>
    <td width="50%"><textarea name="description" type="text" 
cols="40" rows="15" size=100>
    </textarea>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><p><input type="submit" value="Send Mail" name="sendMail"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </p>
    </form>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

mail.jsp

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <%@ page language="java" import="javax.naming.*,java.io.*,javax.mail.*,
    javax.mail.internet.*,com.sun.mail.smtp.*"%>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>sending mail using contactus form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%
    try{
    Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(System.getProperties());
    Transport transport = new SMTPTransport(mailSession,new URLName("smtp.mail.yahoo.com"));
    transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtps");
    transport.connect("smtp.mail.yahoo.com",465,"myyahooid@yahoo.com","myyahoopassword");
   MimeMessage m = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
   m.setFrom(new InternetAddress(%><%request.getParameter("from")%><%));
   Address[] toAddr = new InternetAddress[] {
   new InternetAddress(%><%request.getParameter("to")%><%)
   };
   m.setRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddr );
   m.setSubject(%><%request.getParameter("subject")%><%);
   m.setSentDate(new java.util.Date());
   m.setContent(%><%request.getParameter("description")%><%, "text/plain");

   transport.sendMessage(m,m.getAllRecipients());
   transport.close();
   out.println("Thanks for sending mail!"); 
   }
   catch(Exception e){
   out.println(e.getMessage());
   e.printStackTrace();
   }
   %>
   </body>
```

Now, I want to create a simple CONTACTUS form in which I'll eliminate the "TO" field from "mailFORM.html" file for obvious reasons. As I only want any visitor to visit my website and send email to "mycompanyid@domain.com" by entering FROM, NAME, SUBJECT and description.

So how can I eliminate this problem of entering username and passwod. As I can't create a code in which I 've entred passord here. I can't create separate codes for different smtp's...as VISITIR visting my website contactus page can fill the form by entering his/her email from any domain i'e gmail, yahoo etc.

To conclude I just want to create form like this(taking any anonymous website) which sends the details to company's specific email-ids like "mycompanyid@domain.com"
        http://www.tutorialspoint.com/about/contact_us.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard code your To email id in your JSP file, but its a good practice avoid writing your java code in JSP, should write only method call.

```
private final String TO_EMAIL = "something@domain.com";
```

see my code it works for all SMTPS.

```
package com.naveed.workingfiles;

import org.apache.commons.mail.DefaultAuthenticator;
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailAttachment;
 import org.apache.commons.mail.MultiPartEmail;

public class Mail {
String senderID;
String senderPassword;
String hostName;
int portNumber;
String attachmentPath;
String subject;
String body;
String cc;
String bcc;


// #=============================================================================================#
public String getBcc() {
    return bcc;
}

// #=============================================================================================#
public void setBcc(String bcc) {
    this.bcc = bcc;
}

// #=============================================================================================#
public String getCc() {
    return cc;
}

// #=============================================================================================#
public void setCc(String cc) {
    this.cc = cc;
}

// #=============================================================================================#
public String getBody() {
    return body;
}

// #=============================================================================================#
public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body;
}

// #=============================================================================================#
public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
}

// #=============================================================================================#
public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}

// #=============================================================================================#

public String getSenderID() {
    return senderID;
}

// #=============================================================================================#
public void setSenderID(String senderID) {
    this.senderID = senderID;
}

public String getSenderPassword() {
    return senderPassword;
}

// #=============================================================================================#
public void setSenderPassword(String senderPassword) {
    this.senderPassword = senderPassword;
}

// #=============================================================================================#
public String getHostName() {
    return hostName;
}

// #=============================================================================================#
public void setHostName(String hostName) {
    this.hostName = hostName;
}

// #=============================================================================================#
public int getPortNumber() {
    return portNumber;
}

// #=============================================================================================#
public void setPortNumber(int portNumber) {
    this.portNumber = portNumber;
}

// #=============================================================================================#
public String getAttachmentPath() {
    return attachmentPath;
}

// #=============================================================================================#
public void setAttachmentPath(String attachmentPath) {
    this.attachmentPath = attachmentPath;
}

// #=============================================================================================#
public void sendMail(String receiverId) {

    try {
        // this below commented line for the HTML body text
        // MultiPartEmail htmlEmail = new HtmlEmail();
        // OR
        // HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();

        MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
        // setting the port number
        email.setSmtpPort(getPortNumber());
        // authenticating the user
        email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(getSenderID(),
                getSenderPassword()));
        // email.setDebug(true);
        email.setSSL(true);
        // setting the host name
        email.setHostName(getHostName());
        // setting the rciever id

        email.addTo(receiverId);

        // check for user enterd cc or not
        if (getCc() != null) {
            // add the cc
            email.addCc(getCc());
        }
        // check for user enterd bcc or not
        if (getBcc() != null) {
            // add the bcc
            email.addBcc(getBcc());
        }
        // setting the sender id
        email.setFrom(getSenderID());
        // setting the subject of mail
        email.setSubject(getSubject());
        // setting message body
        email.setMsg(getBody());
        // email.setHtmlMsg("<h1>"+getBody()+"</h1>");

        // checking for attachment attachment
        if (getAttachmentPath() != null) {
            // add the attachment
            EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
            attachment.setPath(getAttachmentPath());
            attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
            email.attach(attachment);
        }

        // send the email
        email.send();
        // System.out.println("Mail sent!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // System.out.println("Exception :: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}// sendmail()
}// mail
```

only you need to save all respective domain details (hostname,port), based on user email set all setters.
down load all required libraries.

Comment: ok @NAVEEED, so what about other things which I've mentioned...to create contactus form in jsp by avoiding enetring username/password for server. Please read the post again sir

Comment: @nAvEed...I read your code(but used my code), it was awesome and can help other. So for the same reason I'm accepting it as answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just hardcore the `Message.RecipientType.TO` variable.

Somewhere you can define a static variable `MY_MAIL` and use `MY_MAIL` instead of `request.getParameter("to")`

Make sure to include the senders e-mail somewhere in the code though, such that you can contact them whenever neccessary.

Also a few other considerations:

- Please read about seperating the actual Java code from a JSP page, you can find enough links for that on google.
- You are importing classes, but then are never using the imports anymore.
- There are useless `%><%` in the code, I don't even know where they are for.

Comment: ok, considering what you mentioned...I know to store TO address somewhere. Till the time I want to solve other  specifications.  Please answer what I've asked for. I'l try to follow your considerations

Comment: @AmanChawla That is not possible in this way. Your code shows how to send an e-mail from a known address (with username/password login) to a certain destination. You will never actually login as your user. So consider sending the mail to yourself basically. From example from the webserver to the webserver, or from the webserver to your personal mail, etc.

Comment: ok @skiwi, any idea how can I do that..many users on this site and others are doing in the same way by entering username and passowrd. So, I wonder how contactus/feedback forms are created in jsp by visitor just entering his/her emailid, subject and message to sent an email.

Comment: @AmanChawla Well I mean it is not per se wrong to do it like this, but it would require you to build some table of all possible domains, and then let the user trust you to handle his credentials carefully. If you want to get rid of the user/password, then you cannot let the user send the mail directly to you via his own account.